# Timing functions correctly in Express, Node and Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on an app were a parent user needs to create a student object that can be accessed by both the parent user and teacher users. Everything is working right except this one thing. When the parent user creates the student, it redirects to the user's dash where the newly created student should display. However, the student doesn't display until I log out and back in. I'm assuming that this is because my code doesn't run in the order I want it to, but I have no idea. I've been stuck here for a couple days. Help!

Here's the route handling for creating a student

EDIT:
I got it to work by refactoring things here almost entirely. I was creating a student document and saving it and then pushing that document into an array on the parent object. That was dumb for two reasons. One, it wasn't displaying properly in terms of timing. Two, if I ever wanted to update the student, I needed to update it in multiple instances. Here, I'm creating the document and adding a reference to an array on the parent object. Now when I edit/delete a student, I do it in one place, and the `ObjectID` is immediately accessible for the `Student.findById()` that runs in the `"users/:id"` route. Here's my updated code:

```
CREATE STUDENT
        router.post("/users/:id/createStudent", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
          const firstName = req.body.firstName,
          lastName = req.body.lastName,
          age = req.body.age,
          instrument = req.body.instrument,
          parent = {
                  id: req.user._id,
                  username: req.user.username
                },
          newStudent = {
                  firstName: firstName,
                  lastName: lastName,
                  age: age,
                  instrument: instrument,
                  parent: parent
                }
        Student.create(newStudent,  function(err){
            if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    req.flash("error", "error")
            } else {
                    res.redirect("/users/:id")     
                    }
                })        
    });
```

And the Dashboard template:

```
<%- include ("../partials/header") %>


// 
code for teachers exists here
//

<% } else if(user.isTeacher === false) {%>
<h1 class="ui huge header"><%= user.username%>'s Dashboard</h1>
<h2 class="ui big header">Here are your students:</h2>
<% if(students.length === 0) {%>
    <p>Oops! Looks like you haven't registered a student. <a href="/users/<%= user._id %>/createStudent">You can do that here.</a> </p>
<% } else { %>
    <div class="ui relaxed divided list">
        <% students.forEach(function(student){ %>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <%= student.firstName %> <%= student.lastName %> 
                    <ul>
                        
                        <li>
                            <a  class="ui secondary mini basic button" 
                                id="assignments" 
                                href="/student/<%= student._id%>">
                                    <%= student.firstName %>'s Assignments
                            </a>
                            <form action="/student/<%= student._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                                <button class="ui negative mini basic button" id="assignments">
                                    Remove Student
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% }) %>
        <p><a href="/users/<%= user._id %>/createStudent">Add a new student.</a></p>
    </div>
<% } %>
<%}%>
</div>
</div>
<%- include ("../partials/footer") %>
```

Here's the student model:

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose"), 
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const StudentSchema= new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    age: String,
    instrument: String,
    assignments: [
         { id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"Assignment"
         },
         title: String
        }     
    ],
    parent: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },
    teacher: [{
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"User"
        },
        username: String
    }]
});

const Student = mongoose.model("student", StudentSchema);

module.exports = Student;
```

Comment: The problem is likely that you are pulling the "profile" of the teacher when they hit the page but aren't adapting/updating/refetching it when the student object is created. That's why it only exists after a reload of the page. I would suggest adding the object directly to the teachers profile that you have (currentUser.students) unless there's data in there that isn't readily available on the client. If that's the case, then send the final object back to the client and adapt it from that.

Comment: Okay so I hear you saying that I should do something to refresh the profile within the template so that when the page renders, I'm not using old data, I'm using the updated version?

Comment: That is what I meant. Although the more I look at your student creation logic, the more questions I have. There's some missing logic in your function (I think).  You are treating your functions like they should fire and then do a thing, but your overall function is not marked as async and you aren't returning any value for the functions. Can you provide more context around the `Student` class?

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you can't tell, I'm really new at this. I added the model for the Student class for reference. User has a boolean called "isTeacher" that is set to false by default. if isTeacher === false, the logged in user is a Parent. when a Parent creates a student, that student gets pushed into an array on the Parent object and they they should be able to view assignments created by Teachers for that student specifically. Therefore, students come with an empty assignments array that the Teacher will have access to fill and the Parent will have access to view.

Comment: return `user.save()` otherwise it won't be part of your promise chain (there might be other issues happening too, but that one pops out)

Comment: willis, just added that, but the issue persists. I added a console.log(currentUser) to the template and it shows that the student doesn't even get pushed into the array until the user logs out and logs back in. It's like the push function doesn't fire until the user logs in.

Comment: Log the `user` (server side) before redirecting the user to see if it's pushed to the array before the redirect. If it's not updated there, then the mongoose commands need to be waited on before redirecting the user.

Comment: It's not pushed in. I though that having the redirect call within the .then would cause it to be the last line run?

Comment: @technicallynick is there any way you would recommend going about waiting for the Mongoose commands?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't messed with Mongoose directly like this. Without looking at the documentation, there are two possibilities. Each command likely has a callback method or it will return a `Promise`. If it's the later, then it's a simple effort of using `.then()` or `await` depending on your preference. If it's the former, then with each command you need to seed the next function within the callback of the previous.

Comment: @technicallynick, I managed to get it all sorted out. Thanks for your help!